# Dereferencing a pointer to a dropped value and the memory is still there

Tags: rust, unsafe

I'm playing with unsafe rust and trying to implement and I've found something I don't understand. I thought for sure I'd have a dangling pointer and that I'd get some kind of runtime error when trying to run this, but I don't.

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("s1");
    let s1_raw_ptr: *const String = &s1;
    drop(s1);
    
    unsafe {
        let s = &*s1_raw_ptr;
        println!("s recovered from raw pointer: {:?}", s);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
s recovered from raw pointer: "s1"
```

I thought that when a value goes out of scope in Rust that it is immediately cleaned up. How is it that dereferencing a raw pointer to a now-dropped value is working?

Comment: Dropping a `String` frees its heap allocation, which means that it either returns that memory to the OS or (more often) marks it as free for _future allocations_. It's undefined behavior to access the memory after it has been freed, but if you do that anyway, you may find the old contents there (until something else overwrites it). There is no requirement for freeing something "cleans it up", that would needlessly slow down deallocation.

Comment: See this [hotel analogy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794) for why accessing data after its been deallocated can still look valid.

Comment: Thanks all for your input. That totally makes sense and is what I suspected. That hotel analogy is great and very memorable.

Comment: This is _Undefined Behavior_, and _you cannot draw any logical conclusions from undefined behavior_. The moment there is UB in the program (and even before it, since UB travels back in time!) any reasoning about the program is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a String is dropped in Rust, ultimately what ends up getting called is [`Allocator::deallocate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/alloc/trait.Allocator.html#tymethod.deallocate) on the system allocator. After this, using the data is undefined behaviour, so anything could happen! But in practice what tends to happen if there aren't any funky compiler optimizations is that you just get whatever data is stored in memory there. If there aren't any new allocations at that place, then you just get whatever data was there before.

When a memory allocation is freed, nothing happens to the allocation. Clearing the data by setting it to all zero (or some other value) would be pointless, since any newly allocated memory always needs to be initialized by the user of that memory.

Answer (score 0):

It is a dangling pointer, the old data just happens to still be there. There's no runtime error because there's no reason for it, it's just undefined behaviour. You wrote a string to memory, dropped it and then read from that same memory again. But dropping it doesn't overwrite that memory, and if it did, it still wouldn't cause an error. The reason you thought there would be an error is that dangling pointers don't usually point to the same thing afterwards and trying to do something with that data causes errors. The dangling pointer itself doesn't cause any errors.

From this answer on another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/23361026 :

> You rent a hotel room. You put a book in the top drawer of the bedside table and go to sleep. You check out the next morning, but "forget" to give back your key. You steal the key!

> A week later, you return to the hotel, do not check in, sneak into your old room with your stolen key, and look in the drawer. Your book is still there. Astonishing!
> How can that be? Aren't the contents of a hotel room drawer inaccessible if you haven't rented the room?

> Well, obviously that scenario can happen in the real world no problem. There is no mysterious force that causes your book to disappear when you are no longer authorized to be in the room. Nor is there a mysterious force that prevents you from entering a room with a stolen key.

> The hotel management is not required to remove your book. You didn't make a contract with them that said that if you leave stuff behind, they'll shred it for you. If you illegally re-enter your room with a stolen key to get it back, the hotel security staff is not required to catch you sneaking in. You didn't make a contract with them that said "if I try to sneak back into my room later, you are required to stop me." Rather, you signed a contract with them that said "I promise not to sneak back into my room later", a contract which you broke.

> In this situation anything can happen. The book can be there—you got lucky. Someone else's book can be there and yours could be in the hotel's furnace. Someone could be there right when you come in, tearing your book to pieces. The hotel could have removed the table and book entirely and replaced it with a wardrobe. The entire hotel could be just about to be torn down and replaced with a football stadium, and you are going to die in an explosion while you are sneaking around.

> You don't know what is going to happen; when you checked out of the hotel and stole a key to illegally use later, you gave up the right to live in a predictable, safe world because you chose to break the rules of the system.

To summarise, it gets "cleaned up", but no memory is actually overwritten.